# JUnit5 assertAll

Tags: java, junit5

The code is as shown below. I want it go test all the elements of keyNames. 
But, it stops if any test fails and doesn't iterate through all array elements. 
My understanding being, in assertAll all assertions are executed, and any failures should be reported together.

Thanks for your time and help.

```
private void validateData(SearchHit searchResult, String [] line){

        for(Integer key : keyNames){
            String expectedValue = getExpectedValue(line, key);
            String elementName = mappingProperties.getProperty(key.toString());

            if (elementName != null && elementName.contains(HEADER)){
                assertAll(
                        () -> assumingThat((expectedValue != null && expectedValue.length() > 0),
                                () -> {
                                        String actualValue = testHelper.getHeaderData(searchResult, elementName);

                                        if(expectedValue != null) {
                                            assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue, " ###Element Name -> " + elementName +" :  Excepted Value ### " + expectedValue + " ### Actual Value ###" + actualValue);
                                        }
                                      }
                                 )
                );

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: My suggestion would be not to have so many logic in the test. Tests are meant to be a documentation. And it should make easier for people to understand the code.

Comment: Thanks much. Yes, will minimize logic in test method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc of `Assertions.assertAll()` states :

> Asserts that all supplied executables do not throw exceptions.

And actually you provide a single `Executable` in `assertAll()` at each iteration.
So a failure in any iteration of the loop terminates the test execution.

In fact you invoke multiple times `assertAll()` by requesting at most a single assertion at each time :

```
if(expectedValue != null) {
    assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue, " ###Element Name -> " + elementName +" :  Excepted Value ### " + expectedValue + " ### Actual Value ###" + actualValue);
}
```

What you want is doing the reverse : invoking  `assertAll()` by passing multiple `Executable` instances performing the required assertions.

So you could collect them in a `List` with a classic loop and pass it in this way : 
`assertAll(list.stream())` or creating a `Stream<Executable>` without any collect and pass it directly such as `assertAll(stream)`.

Here is a version with Stream (not tested at all) but you should get the idea :

```
Stream<Executable> executables = 
keyNames.stream()
        .map(key-> 
               // create an executable for each value of the streamed list
                ()-> {
                        String expectedValue = getExpectedValue(line, key);
                        String elementName = mappingProperties.getProperty(key.toString());

                        if (elementName != null && elementName.contains(HEADER)){
                             assumingThat((expectedValue != null && expectedValue.length() > 0),
                                            () -> {                                             
                                                    String actualValue = testHelper.getHeaderData(searchResult, elementName);
                                                    if(expectedValue != null) {
                                                        assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue, " ###Element Name -> " + elementName +" :  Excepted Value ### " + expectedValue + " ### Actual Value ###" + actualValue);
                                                    }                                                                            

                                            }
                            );

                        }

                    }
            );
Assertions.assertAll(executables);
```

Comment: @dossani You are welcome :) I updated. Collecting into the List is not required as assertAll() may take a Stream as parameter. So it is still simpler finally. I updated.

Comment: If you're creating a stream of tests / executables, then returning a `DynamicTest` and marking it as a `@TestFactory` is an alternative (see [documentation on DynamicTest](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests)), rendering the `assertAll` unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`assertAll()` groups all assertions and errors that were passed to that invocation of `assertAll()`. It *won't* group assertions across all invocations that occur during the test method.

In the code you posted, you pass a single assertion lambda into `assertAll()`. It won't group errors across the multiple keys, as each `key` has a separate invocation of `assertAll()`.

To ensure you separately test all values in a collection, take a look at [parameterized tests](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Looking at passing either a Stream or Collection of Executable to assertAll and see if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @[user31601](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7099148/user31601), parameterized tests (see [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests)) automatically test all cases independently.

This leads to the following (somewhat simpler) code):

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getKeys")
void testKey(String key) { 
    String elementName = mappingProperties.getProperty(key.toString());
    assumeTrue(elementName != null);
    assumeTrue(elementName.contains(HEADER));

    String expectedValue = getExpectedValue(line, key);
    assumeTrue(expectedValue != null);
    assumeTrue(expectedValue.length() > 0);

    String actualValue = testHelper.getHeaderData(searchResult, elementName);
    String doc = String.format("name: %s, expected %s, actual %s", elementName, expectedValue, actualValue);
    assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue, doc);
}

private static Stream<String> getKeys() {
    return keyNames.stream()
}
```