# using junit5 assertAll to assert cucumber data table list of maps

Tags: java, junit, junit5, cucumber-jvm

I have this in a cucumber step definition

```
 secondIT.jsonPathEvaluator = secondIT.response.jsonPath();
```

Then in a different step def, where I assert,  I have

```
  public void employee_response_equals(DataTable responseFields){
              List<Map<String,String>> fields = responseFields.asMaps(String.class,String.class);
              Iterator<Map<String, String>> it = fields.iterator();
              while (it.hasNext()) {
                     Map<String, String> map = it.next(); 
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
                      assertEquals(secondIT.jsonPathEvaluator.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
                     assertAll(
                        // how to use this instead
                );
                    
                 }
             }
            
        }
```

How do I use junit5 `assertAll` to assert values that each of the key fetches(from `jsonPathEvaluator`)  and value from map

I tried to use `assertEquals` but I am not sure if that is correct way as it prints only some  information i.e this `key = data.id` when I comment that line it prints everything

```
key = data.id
value = 2
key = data.employee_name
value = Garrett Winters
```

Also , I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308316/junit5-assertall) but I am not sure how do I make executables for my scenario

sample data table:

```
  And response includes the following employee info
       |key                         |value| 
       | data.id                    | 3 |
       | data.employee_name         | Garrett Winters   |
```

and sample response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "employee_name": "Garrett Winters",
        "employee_salary": 170750,
        "employee_age": 63,
        "profile_image": ""
    },
    "message": "Successfully! Record has been fetched."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertAll` is the wrong tool for the job. It only works if you know exactly how many things you want to assert and you can hard code these. You may instead want to look at using assertion library such as [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/).

Before using AssertJ the problem has to be simplified a bit.

You can remove the header from the data table in your step:

```
    And response includes the following employee info
      | data.id            | 3               |
      | data.employee_name | Garrett Winters |
```

Then can [tell Cucumber you want this data as map by changing the DataTable to a map](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable). Cucumber will tell you if it can't work out what you wanted.

```java
@Then("response includes the following employee info")
public void employee_response_equals(Map<String, String> expectedFields){
```

Once you have the information as a map, you use the expected keys to collect all keys from the json response.

```java
Map<String, Object> actualFields = expectedFields.keySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(expectedKey -> expectedKey, expectedKey -> jsonPathEvaluator.get(expectedKey)));
```

Then you can use `assertThat` from AssertJ to compare the two maps.

```java
assertThat(actualFields).containsAllEntriesOf(expectedFields);
```

When the fields don't match up you'll get a nice message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting map:
 <{"data.employee_name"="Nora Jones", "data.id"="3"}>
to contain:
 <[data.id=3, data.employee_name=Garrett Winters]>
but could not find the following map entries:
 <[data.employee_name=Garrett Winters]>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. When I tried above  approach , I get `Reference to 'get' is ambiguous, both 'get()' and 'get(String)' match` . Also , is `employeeInfo` that is used above an empty map ?

Comment: You'll have to replace the method reference with a lambda then.

Comment: `employeeInfo` should be `expectedFields`

Comment: Yes , `expectedFields` and `actualFields` prints two different key and values . So `actualFields` is created by taking reference from `expectedFields` and then extracting only those keys from `jsonPathEvaluator`  ?.  The part that is confusing to me is how `actualFields` is making `data.id` and `data.employee_name` as keys  and values are taken from `jsonPathEvaluator` . Can you please explain a bit ?

Comment: The string `data.id` comes from the data table in the feature file. Cucumber converts the table to the `expectedFields` map. Then for all the keys in the `expectedFields` map we create a new map, that consists of the key from `expectedFields` and the actual data. We get the data by  using the `jsonPathEvaluator`.

Comment: The `Collectors.toMap` takes two arguments. The first is how the items in the stream (the expected keys` should be turned into a key for the new map. We're using `expectedKey -> expectedKey` so the key doesn't change.

Comment: The second argument is another lambda that turns the expected key into a value in the map. `expectedKey -> jsonPathEvaluator.get(expectedKey)` so here we say the value is the value provided by the `jsonPathEvaluator` for the expected key.